# Covering a coherent sheaf on $\mathbb{P}^n$ with a sum of invertibles.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $F$ be a coherent sheaf on $\mathbb{P}^n$. Why do there exist integers $N$ and $p$ such that there is a surjection $$\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^n}(p)^{\oplus N}\rightarrow F\rightarrow 0\;?$$

I might be misinterpreting a book, so if the above is false, then what would a similar true statement be?

Comment: Do you know the theorem of Serre that says for a coherent $F$, there exists some $n_0$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$ we have $F(n)$ is generated by global sections?

Comment: Deleted previous comments because I was wrong. I must also admit I found a proof of my statement in the same book. I'm terribly sorry!

Comment: Since I'm new here I don't know what the right way to handle this is. But if necessary this question can be marked as "closed" or something to that effect.

Comment: Well... Just in case this'll be helpful to someone, the above is corollary 5.4.3 on page 62 (page 36 of the pdf) in George Kempf's book: http://bib.tiera.ru/b/72466.